# (Excel) How to make index function work in array formula

Tags: excel

I have some trouble in doing the query, which should return sum of days until satisfy some condition for people who satisfy the condition.

For example:

```
+----+-----------+------------+         
| ID | Condition |    Date    |             
+----+-----------+------------+           
|  1 | False     | 2012-01-01 |           
|  1 | False     | 2012-01-02 |         
|  1 | True      | 2012-01-03 |   
|  1 | True      | 2012-01-04 |        
|  2 | False     | 2012-01-01 |        
|  2 | False     | 2012-01-02 |                    
|  3 | False     | 2012-01-01 |        
|  3 | True      | 2012-01-02 |        
+----+-----------+------------+
```

What I expect:  (2 + 0 + 1) = 3

My function is like:
{=SUM( IF( Table[Condition] = True , Index( Table[Date] , Match( Table[Condition]&Table[ID] , Table[Condition]&Table[ID] , 0 ) - Index( Table[Date] , Match( Table[ID] , Table[ID] , 0 ))))}

But my result is just 0 because all index function returns first row, which is [1, False, 2012-01-01]

How can I fix this problem? Great Thx

Update:
I need to go from the date of the first false to the date of first true for the ID if it has true. Every unique ID represents a unique person.
(P.S. Thx! @micstr)

Comment: Welcome Don. Thanks for your explanation , but can you please be clearer about which date you need to sum the days from. For example, in line 3 the first TRUE, why is it 2? Do you need to go from the date of the first false for the ID? You do not mention ID at all in your question.

Comment: @micstr Sorry about that. And yes. I need to go from the date of the first false to the date of first true for the ID if it has true. Every unique ID represents a unique person.